# Set default value for Parse column when new user registers

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am attempting to make a running app, where the user would register and have their own account on the app. But I am using the default Parse signUpViewController when the user is registering. I have a column in the User class in Parse that is marathons completed. Upon registering the value of that column for a new user is undefined, is there a way I can set a default value for when the user registers? Would this be able to be done in the following section?

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

I am using swift, xcode7 along with parse as my backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a cloud code beforeSave on the User class to assign default values if it's newly created. Here's an example bit of code to check out.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    // Check if the User is newly created
    if (request.object.isNew()) {
        // Set default values
        request.object.set("marathonsCompleted", 0);
        request.object.set("someBooleanColumn", true);
        request.object.set("someStringColumn", "someDefaultString");
    }
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: where would I set this in the didSignUpUser?

Comment: It won't be within `didSignUpUser`. Parse cloud code allows you to run functions on the backend infrastructure. It will be a just a little bit of work to set up, but cloud code is extremely powerful and allows you to utilize the same core logic across platforms, deploy new code on-the-fly without need for app updates, and tons of other advantages. Check out the guide online for using cloud code: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide

Comment: Cloud code also allows you to set various triggers such as `beforeSave` and `afterSave` which can be called for any of your Parse classes. They enable you to perform additional logic on Parse's more powerful servers without using any additional API requests. That's also why the answer is written in Javascript rather than Swift. All of Parse's cloud code uses Javascript and trust me when I say it's worthwhile to take the time to utilize it. Cloud code allows you to abstract away nearly all of your app's logic to Parse's backend services

Comment: so this would be included within a javascript file?

Comment: Correct. This would be included in a javascript file. In particular, you will want to install the Parse command line utility to be able to upload and deploy the code. I promise, it's really a simple process and the payoffs are *huge*. Throw this code in your `main.js` file when following the instructions here https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line-installation

Comment: @Russell Can we use cloud code webhooks for this purpoe